Numpy error when export executable in a PC's without Python
When I run my program in Visual Studio Code, it's works without problem
Export code in executable, it's works without problem
When I export in another PC, it's work but there is Numpy error:
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "object_detector_from_camera.py", line 85, in <module> TypeError: __init__():
incompatible constructor arguments. The following argument types are supported:
1. mediapipe.python._framework_bindings.image.Image(image_format: mediapipe::ImageFormat_Format, data: numpy.ndarray[numpy.uint8])     
2. mediapipe.python._framework_bindings.image.Image(image_format: mediapipe::ImageFormat_Format, data: numpy.ndarray[numpy.uint16])     
3. mediapipe.python._framework_bindings.image.Image(image_format: mediapipe::ImageFormat_Format, data: numpy.ndarray[numpy.float32])  Invoked with: kwargs: image_format=<ImageFormat.SRGB: 1>, data=None

In this error compare line 85, in my code line 85 is:
image = mp.Image(image_format=mp.ImageFormat.SRGB, data=img)
I Export my code with pyinstaller with this command line:
pyinstaller C:\Users\pc_test1\Desktop\schifo\object_detector_from_camera.py --noconsole --onefile
Python 3.12.1
mediapipe                 0.10.14
numpy                     2.0.0
opencv-contrib-python     4.10.0.84
opencv-python             4.10.0.84
pip                       23.2.1
pyinstaller               6.9.0

I think my problem depends by the lack of some files in the Build folder
Do you have any ideas?
All my PCs is Windows 10 22H2
My code:
import os
import cv2
import json
import numpy as np
import time
import sys
import imutils
import mediapipe as mp
from mediapipe.tasks import python
from mediapipe.tasks.python import vision


#@markdown We implemented some functions to visualize the object detection results. <br/> Run the following cell to activate the functions.
import cv2
import numpy as np

MARGIN = 10  # pixels
ROW_SIZE = 10  # pixels
FONT_SIZE = 1
FONT_THICKNESS = 1
TEXT_COLOR = (255, 0, 0)  # red


def visualize(
    image,
    detection_result
) -> np.ndarray:
  """Draws bounding boxes on the input image and return it.
  Args:
    image: The input RGB image.
    detection_result: The list of all "Detection" entities to be visualize.
  Returns:
    Image with bounding boxes.
  """
  for detection in detection_result.detections:
    # Draw bounding_box
    bbox = detection.bounding_box
    start_point = bbox.origin_x, bbox.origin_y
    end_point = bbox.origin_x + bbox.width, bbox.origin_y + bbox.height
    cv2.rectangle(image, start_point, end_point, TEXT_COLOR, 3)

    # Draw label and score
    category = detection.categories[0]
    category_name = category.category_name
    probability = round(category.score, 2)
    result_text = category_name + ' (' + str(probability) + ')'
    text_location = (MARGIN + bbox.origin_x,
                     ROW_SIZE + bbox.origin_y - (MARGIN + 10))
    cv2.putText(image, result_text, text_location, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,
                FONT_SIZE, TEXT_COLOR, FONT_THICKNESS)

  return image

# STEP 2: Create an ObjectDetector object.
base_options = python.BaseOptions(model_asset_path='efficientdet_lite0.tflite')
options = vision.ObjectDetectorOptions(base_options=base_options,
                                       score_threshold=0.5)
detector = vision.ObjectDetector.create_from_options(options)



# STEP 5: Process the detection result. In this case, visualize it.

cv2.waitKey(0)

# cv2.waitKey(0)
pTime = 0
cTime = 0

s = 0
# if len(sys.argv) > 1:
#     s = sys.argv[1]

print(s)
print("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa")
    

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(s)

while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    img = cv2.flip(img, 1)
    #imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    #image = mp.Image.create_from_file(img)
    image = mp.Image(image_format=mp.ImageFormat.SRGB, data=img)
    detection_result = detector.detect(image)
    print(detection_result)
    image_copy = np.copy(image.numpy_view())
    annotated_image = visualize(image_copy, detection_result)
    rgb_annotated_image = cv2.cvtColor(annotated_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    #cv2.imshow("temp", rgb_annotated_image)
    cTime = time.time()
    fps = 1/(cTime-pTime)
    pTime = cTime
    annotated_image = imutils.resize(annotated_image, width=720)
    cv2.putText(annotated_image, str(int(fps)), (10,70), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 3, (0,255,255), 3)
    cv2.imshow("window", annotated_image)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
          break


Are all your import items properly installed without error?

What are you meaning for: import items
programs installed with pip?

That error message says that img is None when trying to call mp.Image() (nothing to do with numpy). Did cap.read() actually succeed? The tutorial in the OpenCV docs (https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html) has a good example with all the necessary error handling.
